# Firebug like plugin for Safari browser

Tags: safari, firebug

Is there a development tool plugin for Safari much like how there exists the Firebug plugin for Firefox?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Firebug is great, but Safari provides its own built-in development tools.

If you haven't already tried Safari's development kit, go to Safari-->Preferences-->Advanced, and check the box next to "Show Develop menu in menu bar".

Once you have the Develop menu enabled, you can use the Web Inspector to get a lot of the same functionality that Firebug provides.

Comment: Note this is Mac-only. There's no Web Inspector built into the Windows release :(

Comment: @Jongosi this is not mac only available for windows too, & I using that, it has firebug ad-on for safari as well. :)

Comment: @Aamir You are right! It's there under Advanced settings. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

http://getfirebug.com/lite/Safari.html

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: I have added firebuglite, but seems that it doesn't work. Can you advise how to start inspecting element? I have tried all method but it doesn't worked. Can you advise how to start it?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use Firebug if Safari already comes with great Developer tools? :)

As Matt said, you can enable them from the preferences menu.

Here you will find an overview, summarized, of the [Safari's Web inspector](http://www.it-gems.com/2013/05/how-to-debug-web-page-safari.html), and how to use it:

Comment: I´m not against Firebug. Was just answering the question and showing what you can do with the developer tools in Safari. I like Firebug, pretty much like the other developer tools in Chrome, Safari and even IE.

Comment: No Jordi, Chrome, Safari & IE developer tools do not even come close to the power of Firebug: it is immensely powerful and I for one would struggle to work without it.

Comment: “Then, multiply the ignorance of that question by 100. Then, you’re not even close to the ignorance of the question in this answer” It is okay to have an opinion. It is NOT okay to be rude whilst having an opinion. I’ve used both Firebug and Safari Developer tools and, surprisingly, can use both quite effectively. There was nothing wrong with Jordi’s answer. There was a LOT wrong with your comment.

Comment: @FeloneousCat thx! I just ignore those kind comments to be honest. No point in wasting time.... and agree, I just tend to use the built-in developer extensions cause it is just quicker, whatever it is Safari, Firefox, IE or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the builtin [developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html), there is none that i know of. You might, however, be able to use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: I don't find anywhere the builtin dev tools,where's it?

Comment: There is more info at http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

The Safari built in dev tool is great. I have to admit that Firebug on Firefox is my long time favorite, but I think that the Safari tool do a great job too!

Answer (score 0):

I work a lot with CSS panel and it's too slow in Safari Web Inspector. Apple knows about this problem and promise to fix this bug with freezes, except this thing web tools is much more powerful and convenient than firebug in mozilla, so waiting for fix.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug lite plugin in Safari extensions didn't work (it's made by slicefactory, I don't think it's offical).
btw, #2 works for me!

Answer (score -1):

If you want **firebug** for Safari, you just have to go to the [apple extensions](http://extensions.apple.com) and search for Firebug

[Firebug](https://extensions.apple.com/?q=firebug)

Comment: "0 results found for 'firebug'"