# View Source of PHP Generated HTML Select Menu

Tags: php, html

I'm using PHP to generate the select menu for an HTML web form as follows:

```
$foods = array( 
    '1' => 'fruit',
    '2' => 'pizza',
    '3' => 'bread',
    '4' => 'nuts',
);
```

Here's the code for the HTML select input:

```
<select id="food" name="food">
    <option value="*">- No Selection - </option>
    <?php 
        $output = "";
        $selected = false;

        foreach($foods as $food => $value) {
            $food = htmlspecialchars($food);
            $output .= "<option value=\"$food\"";
            if ($food == $pcSymptomSearch) {
                $selected = true;
                $output .= " selected";
            }
            $output .= ">$value</option>";
        }
        echo $output;
    ?>
</select>
```

I've noticed when viewing the source in Safari/Mac OS X that the select input generated by PHP appears on one line like this, which makes reading/debugging a bit tricky:

```
<option value="1">fruit</option><option value="2">pizza</option><option value="3">bread</option><option value="4">nuts</option>                     </select>
```

Is there a way to make each option appear on one line like this:

```
    <option value="1">fruit</option>
    <option value="2">pizza</option>
    <option value="3">bread</option>
    <option value="4">nuts</option>                     
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, you can, try this: `$output .= ">$value</option>\n\t\t\t";`. But, really, its not needed...

Comment: Do you know about `Firebug` tool? For example, for Safari you can use such solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648866/firebug-like-plugin-for-safari-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is when you are building your string for output add a `\n` (newline character) every place that the newline would be appropriate.

```
 $output .= ">$value</option>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$output .= ">$value</option>";
```

with

```
$output .= ">$value</option>\n";
```